# Comparing fluorescence intensity of finger print residue after 5 contacts

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, imagej, fiji

I have an image as follows that shows the residue of fluorescent powder left on a surface after 5 sequential contacts. Is it possible to quantify the a difference in the amount of residue between contacts?

[image]

I have looked at Fiji/ImageJ and selected each finger print at a time to get the mean grey value but I don't see much difference to be honest. Any help or thoughts would be very much appreciated. Happy to think about python or matlab.

Comment: How would someone who is good at analysing residues decide? And what is the order, by the way?

Comment: Good question. The order is 1=bottom left. 2 top left. 3= bottom right, 4 middle right and 5= top right. Are you referring to how quantitative this needs to be?

Comment: No, my question means.... whatever an experienced looker at residues would look for is probably what your image processing needs to look for.

Comment: Hmm this is true but from a naive perspective I would have thought that the sum of the intensity of the pixels for each print 1-5 would give a rough indication of how much power was left by each contact. Do you think this is too naive/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the quantification of the intensities to be useful, I would imagine you would need to assume your image was evenly lit and that any fluorescence you see isn't a result of oversaturation.  That being said, in principle, you could contour the given fingerprint, duplicate it to a new image, and then measure the stack histogram after adjusting the threshold such that regions darker than your fingerprint powder are set to black.  Perhaps the change in distribution will illustrate the change that occurs, if any.

Edit:

First: merge the RGB channels by adding them to one another using the channel calculator function.  Your signal is the result of multiple colors, so splitting it does not make sense to me here.

The steps would then be:

1. Duplicate your given print to a new window.
2. Use "Adjust Threshold" to set a threshold of 0-n, where n is the highest intensity that doesn't include your fingerprint.
3. Run the command "Edit/Selection/Create Selection."
4. Run the command "Edit/Clear."
5. Press "ctrl+H" to measure the histogram of the pixels, and then "List" to get the actual values.
6. Repeat for each print and plot on the same chart.

When you are already obtaining the actual histogram values, and not just the range from the particle analyzer, then I'm not sure there's much else that I can personally suggest.

Comment: Hi J. Kovacs, sounds very interesting. There is definitely an angle to the light from above so all fingerprints are lit differently. However I am not seeing oversaturation in the histogram. I then look at the green chanel because it seems to give the least background. I've selected each fingerprint in turn and measured the raw integrated density. You can see a downward trend in total intensities from 1-5. Can you clarify what you mean by measuring the histogram please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say that you are measuring the histogram, if not for "Analyze/Histogram," which should, at least from your images, show some change from your first to last print.

Comment: I've noted above the actual steps that I originally suggested.  I hope that it's clearer now.  If you are just aiming to be able to show that the amount of powder decreases over time, you should get a change in the histogram curves which would be sufficient for your purposes.  If you would repeat this experiment to try to get significance, you should work on standardizing the lighting angle for future tests.